# Generated WSDL Proxy has class named "System"

Tags: c#, .net, soap, visual-studio-2013, wsdl

I'm working with a third party service whose WSDL defines a class named `System`. Using Add Service Reference, Visual Studio generates a proxy that has a class named `System`, which causes all kinds of compilation problems.

I'm looking for the best way to avoid this problem without breaking the contract.

I tried modifying the Reference.cs, but what I did screwed up the serialization. Also, since this file can change every time someone updates the service reference, this is not a good long-term solution.

I'm curious if anybody has encountered a problem like this before, and how to best solve it.

The complexType is as follows:

```
<xsd:complexType name="System">
  <xsd:all>
    <xsd:element name="timer_frequency" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="acceptable_timer" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="fail_instructions" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="dispatch_instructions" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="system_descr" type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Have you tried generating types in a different namespace? See /namespace option in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: @EugeneOsovetsky: did you realize you pointed to the .NET 2.0 page for WSDL.EXE, and we don't even know if he's using that obsolete tool?

Comment: Which "import tool" are you using? You should first try using "Add Service Reference". If that doesn't work, then try "svcutil.exe".

Comment: Using Add Service Reference. I'm setting a meaningful namespace too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ultimate solution to this problem involved generating the service reference (I chose to do so via `svcutil.exe`), and then manually modifying the `System` class to be called something else (I picked `Sys`). I also had to change the `SoapTypeAttribute` to include a `TypeName="System"`.

Then, whenever they update their API, I have to do it all over again. Not great, but gets things working.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working around your issue you should have your service namespace changed to something else other than "System".

When you add the service reference, you have the option to provide the namespace you want it under, however the using System will be automatically added on the Top which will screw things up. If the service cannot be modified, I guess you should refrain from adding the reference and generate the proxy manually, modify it and add to your project.

Comment: The service namespace isn't System. One of the classes defined by the service is.